# See lots of docker error messages in /var/log/messages

Tags: docker

In our environment, we have a jenkins server ussed for performing builds on docker host. There is this job that runs for about 4 hours and exits successfully, on a few occasions i have seen the job running on docker host inside a container and the process inside the container in sleeping state. It had to be aborted as the container was running and the job was in sleeping state. So i see a lot of error messages in /var/log/messages for the container as below. I am trying to see if these messages can lead me to anything close to why the process went in sleeping state. I am unable to understand what they mean. Can someone help in understanding what they are?

May 26 06:06:01 docker-host dockerd: time="2020-05-26T06:06:01-04:00" level=error msg="  \"Path\": \"/containers/275263c38860a5bdc194d4e133a249556de426d14fc00ec41f80053a5e684c91/start\"," plugin=effad85a32975446929f563867ae047e01964b32b03b567997139bb343bbc0eb

May 26 06:06:01 docker-host containerd: time="2020-05-26T06:06:01.125558014-04:00" level=info msg="shim containerd-shim started" address="/containerd-shim/moby/275263c38860a5bdc194d4e133a249556de426d14fc00ec41f80053a5e684c91/shim.sock" debug=false pid=91030

May 26 06:06:01 docker-host dockerd: time="2020-05-26T06:06:01-04:00" level=error msg="  \"Path\": \"/containers/275263c38860a5bdc194d4e133a249556de426d14fc00ec41f80053a5e684c91/json\"," plugin=effad85a32975446929f563867ae047e01964b32b03b567997139bb343bbc0eb

May 26 11:39:15 docker-host dockerd: time="2020-05-26T11:39:15-04:00" level=error msg="  \"Path\": \"/v1.39/containers/275263c38860/json\"," plugin=effad85a32975446929f563867ae047e01964b32b03b567997139bb343bbc0eb

May 26 11:39:15 docker-host dockerd: time="2020-05-26T11:39:15-04:00" level=error msg="  \"Path\": \"/v1.39/containers/275263c38860/exec\"," plugin=effad85a32975446929f563867ae047e01964b32b03b567997139bb343bbc0eb

ay 26 11:41:04 docker-host dockerd: time="2020-05-26T11:41:04-04:00" level=error msg="  \"Path\": \"/v1.39/containers/275263c38860/stats?stream=1\"," plugin=effad85a32975446929f563867ae047e01964b32b03b567997139bb343bbc0eb

May 26 11:41:40 docker-host dockerd: time="2020-05-26T11:41:40-04:00" level=error msg="  \"Path\": \"/v1.39/containers/275263c38860/logs?stderr=1\u0026stdout=1\u0026tail=all\"," plugin=effad85a32975446929f563867ae047e01964b32b03b567997139bb343bbc0eb

May 26 11:41:40 docker-host dockerd: time="2020-05-26T11:41:40-04:00" level=error msg="  \"Path\": \"/v1.39/containers/275263c38860/json\"," plugin=effad85a32975446929f563867ae047e01964b32b03b567997139bb343bbc0eb

May 26 11:42:39 docker-host dockerd: time="2020-05-26T11:42:39-04:00" level=error msg="  \"Path\": \"/v1.39/containers/275263c38860/json\"," plugin=effad85a32975446929f563867ae047e01964b32b03b567997139bb343bbc0eb

May 26 11:42:39 docker-host dockerd: time="2020-05-26T11:42:39-04:00" level=error msg="  \"Path\": \"/v1.39/containers/275263c38860/exec\"," plugin=effad85a32975446929f563867ae047e01964b32b03b567997139bb343bbc0eb

May 26 12:05:28 docker-host dockerd: time="2020-05-26T12:05:28-04:00" level=error msg="  \"Path\": \"/v1.39/containers/275263c38860/json\"," plugin=effad85a32975446929f563867ae047e01964b32b03b567997139bb343bbc0eb

May 26 12:05:28 docker-host dockerd: time="2020-05-26T12:05:28-04:00" level=error msg="  \"Path\": \"/v1.39/containers/275263c38860/exec\"," plugin=effad85a32975446929f563867ae047e01964b32b03b567997139bb343bbc0eb

May 26 12:17:55 docker-host dockerd: time="2020-05-26T12:17:55-04:00" level=error msg="  \"Path\": \"/v1.39/containers/275263c38860/json\"," plugin=effad85a32975446929f563867ae047e01964b32b03b567997139bb343bbc0eb

May 26 12:17:55 docekr-host dockerd: time="2020-05-26T12:17:55-04:00" level=error msg="  \"Path\": \"/v1.39/containers/275263c38860/exec\"," plugin=effad85a32975446929f563867ae047e01964b32b03b567997139bb343bbc0eb

May 26 12:49:38 docker-host dockerd: time="2020-05-26T12:49:38-04:00" level=error msg="  \"Path\": \"/v1.39/containers/275263c38860/json\"," plugin=effad85a32975446929f563867ae047e01964b32b03b567997139bb343bbc0eb

May 26 12:52:20 docker-host dockerd: time="2020-05-26T12:52:20-04:00" level=error msg="  \"Path\": \"/v1.39/containers/275263c38860/json\"," plugin=effad85a32975446929f563867ae047e01964b32b03b567997139bb343bbc0eb

Comment: That looks like HTTP access logs (Docker's standard setup speaks HTTP over a Unix socket).  Aside from the sheer number of `exec` calls this doesn't obviously look problematic; it doesn't suggest any specific problem.  What's the actual problem you're encountering?  Can you edit the question to include a [mcve] including any relevant application code?

Comment: You should put the message inside a ``` code flag to improve readability.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks, sorry but I saw those logs after the jenkins job was aborted, also when the container was running i tried doing docker logs <container-id> it didnt return any output.. The actual problem is the job (python script) was seen stuck in console output as if its waiting for something, On docekr host the container was running and the python script was in sleeping state within the container, this suggested to me there was no issue with docker/jenkins, nothing found in catalina.out on jenkins that i can use to get to the root cause.